# Pandas: Comparing columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boolean-logic

Hi i have a data frame made with pandas. I need to compare the value of truth of two columns. I made two new columns: "misslast" and "hitlast"
"hitlast": Its worth TRUE when the column "response" is worth True and the following row form de column "Confidence" is worth True. All other combinations are supposed to be False.
"misslast": Its worth True when the column "response" is False and the following row from the column "confidence" is False also.
They both are comparing if the state of confidence of a the following round matches their performance on the previous round.

This is mi data frame (it actually is a [2539 rows x 19 columns] matrix):

```
      circle_rt    response   circle_number confidence confidence_rt  nose  \
0     12.746130     True              0       True      26.686977  0.000000   
1      5.497027     True              6       True       2.219596  0.120000   
2      3.789324     True              2       True       4.992639  0.118931   
3      7.716839     True              2       True       3.139458  0.067106   
4      4.219006     True              7       True       2.680553  0.000000   
5      6.635735     True              1       True       1.643296  0.015449   
6     12.768281    False              2       True       2.045460  0.000000   
7      4.293818     True              0       True       1.915654  0.060843   
8      2.280957     True              5       True       2.384980  0.000000
```

...

```
32     2.073823     True              4       True       0.614546  0.000000   
33     3.290734    False              7      False       1.675789  0.000000   
34     9.443876    False              6      False       5.116144  0.001011   
35     5.288295     True              8       True       0.642439  0.021680   
36     2.007872     True              0       True       0.948012  0.000000
```

For example when comparing the value of truth of the 6th row in "response" vs the 7th row in "confidence", the value of the "lashit" should be TRUE, becouse they are not equal.
And when comparing the 33th row in column "response" with the 34th row in column "confidence" i should return True.
This is the code

```
df['hitlast']=(df['response']&True) & df['confidence'].shift(1).fillna(0)
df['misslast']=(df["response"]&False) & ((df["confidence"]&False).shift(1).fillna(True))#Creo una columna que Indica True Si el valor de "response" es Falso y ademas "Confidence" de la siguiente jugada es False tambien.
```

My new dataframe adds two columns: Hitlast and misslast

The problem is that misslast is always False and i dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this line:

```
(df["response"]&False) & ((df["confidence"]&False).shift(1).fillna(True))
```

As it will always evaluate to `False` (Anything `& False` will evaluate to `False`)

You could simply use:

```
df['hitlast'] = df['response'] & df['confidence'].shift(-1).fillna(False)
```

and

```
df['misslast'] = ~df['response'] & ~df['confidence'].shift(-1).fillna(True)
```

In action:

```
>>> df
    circle_rt  response  circle_number  confidence  confidence_rt      nose
0   12.746130      True              0        True      26.686977  0.000000
10   3.290734     False              7       False       1.675789  0.000000
11   9.443876     False              6       False       5.116144  0.001011
12   5.288295      True              8        True       0.642439  0.021680
13   2.007872      True              0        True       0.948012  0.000000
>>> df['response'] & df['confidence'].shift(-1).fillna(False)
0     False
10    False
11    False
12     True
13    False
dtype: bool
>>> ~df['response'] & ~df['confidence'].shift(-1).fillna(True)
0     False
10     True
11    False
12    False
13    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: When you get to the 13th row of the column "response" how does it compares with the 14th row of the column "confidence" if there isnt a 14th row? And shouldnt the 10th row of misslast be true instead of the 11th?
Thanks

Comment: @AntonellaMarabotto, The fillna assures that if a row is missing the condition will not evaluation to True, I may have shifted the wrong way, let me re-read your question and I will update.

Comment: @AntonellaMarabotto you were correct.  I was shifting the wrong way.  I have updated my answer.